# reflect.Set slice-of-structs value to a struct, without type assertion (because it's unknown)

Tags: go, reflection

I'm creating a helper package to pop payloads from a queue. It's essential that this helper be agnostic to the struct used by the application importing it.

This (no-op, just example) function will provide a single payload from the queue, of the provided type `like interface{}`:

```
func One(like interface{}) interface{} {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(like)
    one := reflect.New(typ)

    return one.Interface()
}
```

This function provides many payloads:

```
func Many(num int, like interface{}) interface{} {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(like)
    many := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), num, num)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        one := One(typ)
        many.Index(i).Set(one)
    }

    return many.Interface()
}
```

An example of usage is:

```
type Payload struct {
    Id int
    Text string
}

func main() {
    Many(4, Payload{})
}
```

However, the above results in:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type **reflect.rtype is not assignable to type main.Payload
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ud23ZlD3Bx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `reflect.TypeOf` on a `reflect.Value`, which is where `**reflect.rtype` is coming from.

Call your `One` function wth the `like` value directly, and assign that result to the slice.

```
func One(like interface{}) interface{} {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(like)
    one := reflect.New(typ)

    return one.Interface()
}

func Many(num int, like interface{}) interface{} {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(like)
    many := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), num, num)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        one := One(like)
        many.Index(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(one).Elem())
    }

    return many.Interface()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fHF_zrymcI

Comment: Is possible to remove the reflect.SliceOf(typ) and get the same result?

Comment: @fvarj: I'm not sure what you mean, since you can't make a slice without a type. Have you tried to see what happens?